# Discrete mathematics solving recurrence relation with param

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was given this equation to solve and I'm without any idea how to work the parameter which is given as p in the equation and therefore I can't figure out what the correct solution is. Any help would be very much appreciated.

$$a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+(1-p)a_n$$
where $p\in(0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}$ is a given parameter.

Comment: If $p$ were a given number, say $0.75$, what would you do to solve the equation then?  Can you then see how you might generalise to an arbitrary $p$?

Comment: @postmortes as the p is there it's very much confusing for me as I've never came across similar equations. I really have 0 ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: So I probably figured out the general solution as $$a_n=C_1 + C_2 (p - 1)^n$$

Comment: You should write your own answer to your question then, so people can see how you got there :)